# How to raise my exception without displaying the module name

Tags: python

I defined

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass
```

When I raise it, the last traceback line says

```
__main__.MyException: ...
```

Is there a way to make python display the exception without the module where it has been defined, specifically, without the preceding `__main__.`?

```
MyException: ...
```

Comment: What is the *problem* you are trying to solve? You can still catch it with e.g. `except MyException:` (as long as that name is imported).

Comment: catch the exception, read the exception details, print in what ever custom way you need!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest putting it in a `try...except` block:

```py
'''define error'''
try:
    '''code with defined error'''
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```