# Why does a user-defined exception print the module name?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, python-decorators, typechecking

I'm learning Python and am creating my first decorator that checks that the decorated function is passed an object of the correct type, raising an exception if not. I've created a `TypeError` subclass called `TypeNotFoundError` to handle this.

```py
# strict.py

from inspect import signature, _empty

class TypeNotFoundError(TypeError):
    pass

def strict_types(original_function):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        sig = signature(original_function)
        for param, arg in zip(sig.parameters.values(), args):
            try:
                arg_type = param.annotation
                if arg_type == _empty:
                    raise TypeNotFoundError(f"Type annotation not found in function signature")
            except TypeNotFoundError as e:
                print(str(e))
                raise
            if isinstance(arg, arg_type) or isinstance(arg, type(None)):
                continue
            else:
                raise TypeError(f"Parameter '{param.name}' must be {arg_type}")
        return original_function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@strict_types
def test_hint(string: str):
    print(type(string))

@strict_types
def test_no_hint(string):
    print(type(string))
```

When calling `test_no_hint` or directly raising `TypeNotFoundError` in the REPL, it prints `strict.TypeNotFoundError`. Why does it include the module name? Why does the traceback show the line where the error was raised when other built-in errors don't?

```py
>>> import strict as s
>>> s.test_no_hint("I'm not dead yet")
Type hint not found in function signature
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/file_path/strict.py", line 15, in wrapper
    raise TypeNotFoundError(f"Type hint not found in function signature")
strict.TypeNotFoundError: Type hint not found in function signature
```

Also using the `try`-`except` clause here feels a little forced. Is there anything wrong with just using the `raise` statement like so:

```py
if arg_type == _empty:
    raise TypeNotFoundError(f"Type annotation not found in function signature")
```

Is there a better/more standard pattern for doing this?

I tried importing the exception in the REPL and importing the exception into its own module to see if that had any effect (it did not). I can't seem to find any mention of this in the documentation. I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57867461/how-to-raise-my-exception-without-displaying-the-module-name) that is similar but doesn't answer why this occurs or how to omit it.

Comment: Why is it a problem that it tells you exactly what the exception is? In many scenarios this is helpful because it allows you to pinpoint the source of the error better.

Comment: Regarding your question about try-except-raise: Do not catch the exception in the wrapper. Just raise the exception. I don't see the need to catch the exception and re-raise it, but maybe I missed something.

Comment: @Matthias That's what I thought too, the content I was exploring seemed to suggest trying to use try and except whenever dealing with exceptions, but I agree here it seems redundant and unnecessary

Comment: @tripleee It's not a problem per se, I just would like to understand why I see the module name displays for me when in other examples of custom exceptions the module name is not shown. I do think it would be cleaner to not have the module name present.

Comment: "when in other examples of custom exceptions the module name is not shown" - what examples would those be? We can't tell you what's different between your code and those examples if you don't show us an example of the module name not getting printed for a custom exception.

Comment: The reason Python prints the module name is pretty much the same as the reason it prints the exception type name: it helps you know what kind of exception you're dealing with. That's very important for investigating errors, or for catching exceptions when it makes sense to catch them.